# Get Item[i] from listview

Tags: c#, multithreading, listview, thread-safety

I am trying to get an item[i] to a string from a ListView. I just don't seem to understand what I am supposed to do, when the ListView is on another thread.

```
public delegate void getCurrentItemCallBack (int location);
...
private void runAsThread()
{
   While (..>i)
   {
    //I tried the following //Doesn't work.
    //string item_path = listView.Item[i].toString();   

    //attempting thread safe. How do I get it to return a string?
    string item_path = GetCurrentItem(i);
   }
}
private void GetCurrentItem(int location)
{
   if (this.listViewModels.InvokeRequired)
      {
       getCurrentItemCallback d = new getCurrentItemCallback(GetCurrentItem);
       this.Invoke(d, new object[] { location });
      }
      else
      {
       this.listViewModels.Items[location].ToString();
      }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a delegate type that returns a string, not a void, to begin with.

Then, you need the matching method to return a string as well.

```
public delegate string getCurrentItemCallBack (int location);

...

private string GetCurrentItem(int location)
{
   if (this.listViewModels.InvokeRequired)
      {
       getCurrentItemCallback d = new getCurrentItemCallback(GetCurrentItem);
       return this.Invoke(d, new object[] { location });
      }
      else
      {
       return this.listViewModels.Items[location].ToString();
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your relply. On your line:
 return this.Invoke(d, new object[] { location });
I changed it to:
 return this.Invoke(d, new object[] { location }).ToSring(); because I was getting an error.
This works, but when I look at the string returned it includes: "ListViewItem: {C:\test.txt}". 
Is there a way of just returning C:\test.txt

Comment: Got it. All I had to do was change the last line to: return this.lisviewModels.Items [location].Text

Answer (score 0):

Much easier and readable IMO to use a lambda action, no messing around with callbacks or delegates

```
   private void GetCurrentItem(int location)
   {
         if (this.listViewModels.InvokeRequired)
         {
             Invoke( new Action ()=>{
                //do what ever you want to do here
                // this.listViewModels.Items[location].Text;
             })); 
         }
         else
         {
          this.listViewModels.Items[location].Text;
         }
   }
```